# Rails: Nested_form_for and scope, POST creates record twice/duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, nested-forms, nested-form-for

In my form I need my admin scope like this

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @event], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

Now, replacing this with **nested_form_for** (Using Ran Bates' Nested_form gem)

```
<%= nested_form_for [:admin, @event], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

the POST action inserts the new nested task record for this event **twice**!?

Removing the *:admin* scope fixes this, but I could not do without it. What would be a solution here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue originated from messed up controller action. Closing this.